# PostgreSQL: How to get numeric result from string result that IS NOT a number

Tags: postgresql, grafana, grafana-alerts

I want to set an alert rule in visualization tool called Grafana. Problem is, to set alert rule the query result must be numeric, because their tool doesn't support other types ([github issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/46429)).

I want to check whether latest instance `Color` in the table called `colors_of_alerts` of specified `AlertID` is `red_color`. If it is, I want to fire alert, otherwise do nothing. Other possible values except `red_color` are: `green_color` and `yellow_color`.

In ideal world, the following query would be enough:

```
select "Color" from (select "Color" from colors_of_alerts where "AlertID"=72 order by "TimeUTC" desc limit 1) as res where res."Color"='red_circle'
```

The problem is, I need the return of query to be numeric type, but the only way to cast string to integer in PostgreSQL requires the string to hold the number (`'1'`, `'1.901'`, etc.).

I wanted to find something that will work as following: **if "Color"='red_circle' return 1, otherwise return 0**, but PostgreSQL `return` only works in functions, studying the in-outs of which is whole another can of worms for my simple query. So I tried using `if-else` statements:

```
DO $$
begin 
if exists (select "Color" from (select "Color" from colors_of_alerts where "AlertID"=72 order by "TimeUTC" desc limit 1) as res where res."Color"='red_circle') then 
update res set "Color"='1';
else 
update res set "Color"='0';
END IF;
end $$;
```

to set resulting cell with 0 or 1 varchar and then cast that varchar to number via `CAST` or `::integer`, but it causes the issue `SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "res" does not exist`, which probably occurs because of incorrect handling of table alias naming. Please, help me to create my query with simple commands, because I think that my queries are needlessly complex.

Comment: Use `case` for this.

Comment: @MikeOrganek, yes, it works, thank you for your help. I am inexperienced in postgre, so such simple solution eluded me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint from @MikeOrganek I've found the correct commands to do what is needed, hope this will help someone in the future:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN res."Color" = 'red_circle' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END result
FROM
  (SELECT "Color"
   FROM colors_of_alerts
   WHERE "AlertID" = 72
   ORDER BY "TimeUTC" DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS res;
```